# How to iterate json in angular?

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I am getting the following json from a database, and I want to do an ngfor;but I don't know how to do it with this kind of JSON

[link codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbc24ebb)

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let referencia of referencias.rows">
       <div class="card text-center">
           <div class="card-header">

           </div>
           <div class="card-body">
               {{referencia.2}}
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: As per your JSON, you'll require a nested `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your json return from the API first before using it:

In the ts file where you receive your data:

```
referencias = JSON.parse(referencias);
```

And since each `referencia` from `referencias.rows` is an Array, you access it data like this `referencia[arrayIndex]`:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let referencia of referencias.rows">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
        </div>
        // Changed referencia.2 to referencia[2]
        <div class="card-body">
               {{referencia[2]}} // Should show 'AYALA'
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file, I am assuming referencias is the parsed json response of the API. The below solution is to get all the rows.

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let referencia of referencias['rows']">
   <div class="card text-center">
       <div class="card-header">

       </div>
       <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let rowData of referencia">
           {{rowData}}
       </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this works for you.